# Get coordinates of jquery element array

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I want to extract an array of left coordinates (simply numbers) from a matched jquery array. Something similar to this:

```
var array = element.nextAll().position().left
```

Is there a neat way of doing this, perhaps with underscore?

So in this case the jquery array contains a number of divs, from each of them I want to get their jquery `position()` - object and extract the left coordinate. The resulting `array` will contain numbers which is each of the div's left coordinate.

Comment: Add `array` in the question for more understanding.

Comment: Please add more explanation or HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this code:**

```
array = $(element.nextAll()).map(function() {
   return $(this).position().left;
}).get();
```

Please refer this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g25hsdw6/8/)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding to your question...I think this will do in native js not using underscore.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var array = new Array();
  
  $("#content").nextAll().each(function(index)
  {
   array[index] = $(this).position().left;
  });
  
  $("#array").html(array.toString());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Content Text<h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">menu</div>
    <div id="menu1">menu1</div>
</div>

      
 <br />
<h2 id="array">

</h2>
```